# it is possible to create a default retention policy before mapping bucket in influx v2

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

I have updated influx to version 2. However, I still want to support v1. I create a bucket and then map the bucket. This also works, but the retention policy is always null although I set it in the request. Is it possible to create a retention policy for a bucket (mapped or unmapped)?

Comment: How are you creating the DBRP? I use the `influx` cli and everything works fine...

Answer (score 0):

In InfluxDB UI: Data -> Buckets -> Create Bucket -> **Older Than** -> Choose retention policy

Or you can change current retention policy in bucket settings

---

[image]